# Can't Add Service Reference of from WCF project to a WPF client, Error downloading metadata

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, service-reference

I have got an issue adding a service reference from WCF app to a WPF client.

out of four projects two of them are, WCF app which includes a 'WCF Service' with three interface contracts IService1, IService2 IService3(different names irl),
and a WPF Project which is the client side.

when trying to add a service reference to the WPF project it does find the service after pressing 'Discover' in the 'Add Service Reference' window, but once pressing the 'go' button or the 'ok' button it starts to load and then gives an error message.
"An error (Details(link)) occurred while attempting to find services at 'http://localhost:2146/Services/PlayAndChatService.svc'".

In the 'Details' Link it says
"There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:2146/Services/PlayAndChatService.svc/$metadata'."

But, when launching the WCF project by itself it loads perfectly with IIS express.

I tried many solutions that been given here to similar issues but none of them helped.
I already tried:
Build/Rebuild the Solution
Going through web.config looking for mistakes there but all seems to be fine.
Starting the WCF project and trying to add the service reference while the WCF instance is online.
Trying all of the above while running VS as Admin.
and more that I cannot recall.

Here are some code and the error messages, maybe I missed something.

[ErrorMessage in Add Service Reference window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK7xg.jpg)

[ErrorMessage when pressing ok after selecting the service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbhaM.jpg)

Code:
WCF Service:

```
using Common.Models;
using WCFChatAndPlay.ServiceInterfaces;
using DAL.DbOperations;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Common.Enums;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WCFChatAndPlay.Services
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class PlayAndChatService : IUserService, IGameService, IChatService
    {

        #region IUserService
        public bool AddUser(UserModel newUser)
        {
            //Adding user to Db
        }

        public List<UserModel> GetOnlineUsers(UserModel currentUser)
        {
            //Gets all online users
        }

        public UserModel GetUser(UserModel requestedUser)
        {
            //Getting a specific user
        }
        #endregion

        #region IGameService
        public void MovePiece(PlayerModel p, GameCellModel source, GameCellModel destination)
        {
            //Doing some game operations
        }

        public void StartGame(GameModel game)
        {
            //Init Game
        }
        #endregion

        #region IChatService
        public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            //Send Message
        }

        public void SendInvite(UserModel targetUser)
        {
            //Send Invite
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Service1:

```
using Common.Models;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WCFChatAndPlay.ServiceInterfaces
{
    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IChatCallback))]
    interface IChatService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendMessage(string message);

        [OperationContract]
        void SendInvite(UserModel targetUser);

    }

    interface IChatCallback
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void CallbackFunction(string str);
    }
}
```

Service2:

```
using Common.Models;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WCFChatAndPlay.ServiceInterfaces
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IGameService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void StartGame(GameModel game);
        [OperationContract]
        void MovePiece(PlayerModel p, GameCellModel source, GameCellModel destination);
        [OperationContract]
        void EatPiece();
    }
}
```

Service3:

```
using Common.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WCFChatAndPlay.ServiceInterfaces
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IUserService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool AddUser(UserModel newUser);

        [OperationContract]
        UserModel GetUser(UserModel requestedUser);

        [OperationContract]
        List<UserModel> GetOnlineUsers(UserModel currentUser);
    }
}
```

web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You keep saying "Add service reference *from* the WCF project *to* the WPF client". Isn't that backwards? Don't you want a service reference on the WPF project pointing to the WCF one?

Comment: exactly what i meant,
maybe i didn't explain it as i should have,
but it i try to do exactly what you said